# How would I turn this into a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, function

I have this bit of javascript:

```
$('.step_1 li').click(function(event) {
  $(this).find('label').hide();
  $(this).find('input').focus();
});

$('.step_1 li input')
.focus(function(){
  $(this).prev('label').hide();
})
.blur(function(){
  if (!$(this).val()){
    $(this).prev('label').show();
  }
});
```

I'd like to be able to just say `$('.step_1').inputSwap()` so I can reuse it.

So what's the proper wan to create a jQuery function like this? (I'm running jQuery 1.6.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is how you would turn it into a plugin.

```
$.fn.inputSwap = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this)
            .click(function(){
                $(this).find("label").hide();
                $(this).find('input').focus();
            }).find("input").focus(function(){
                $(this).prev('label').hide();
            }).blur(function(){
                $(this).prev('label').show();
            })
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

some optimizations and fixed li

```
$.fn.inputSwap = function(){
    this.find('li').click(function(){
        var $li = $(this);
        $li.find("label").hide();
        $li.find('input').focus();
    }).find("input").focus(function(){
        $(this).prev('label').hide();
    }).blur(function(){
        $(this).prev('label').show();
    });
    return this;
}
```

Comment: the .each() may not even be required in this case, however it wont hurt anything.

Comment: If the OP wants to use the specified selector, you need to add a `find('li')` before each.  The `each(...)` is also redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
function inputSwap( clss ) {
    var j = $( clss );

    j.delegate( 'li', 'click', function () {
        $( this ).find( 'label' ).hide();
        $( this ).find( 'input' ).focus();
    });

    j.delegate( 'input', 'focus', function () {
        $( this ).prev( 'label' ).hide();  
    });

    j.delegate( 'input', 'blur', function () {
        $( this ).prev( 'label' ).toggle( !this.value );
    });
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nbkcP/

Using `delegate` ensures better performance, because you're not binding any click / focus / blur handlers to the corresponding elements directly. Instead, jQuery binds **only one** "live" handler to each `.step_1` element.

Comment: I couldn't find a contact form or anything, so i'll just ask here. @Sime, Do you have the page that was once posted at this link? http://vidasp.net/jquery-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.inputSwap = function(){
    return this.find('li').click(function(event) {
        $(this).find('label').hide().end().find('input').focus();
    }).find('input').focus(function(){
        $(this).prev('label').hide();
    }).blur(function(){
        if (!$(this).val()){
            $(this).prev('label').show();
        }
    });
};
```

Call it with:

```
$('.step_1').inputSwap()
```